# Images sometimes are not saved in the Wayback Machine

Tags: bug, status-norepro, images, backup

Images sometimes are not saved in the [Wayback Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine).

Example: https://web.archive.org/web/20201230113805/https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/161854/roads-classification-in-spain/161855

[image]

I have no idea if the issue is on the Wayback Machine side, Stack Exchange or Imgur.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's Wayback's problem.  I'll get back to you in a sec.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not seeing that, I see the full image:

[image]

It was probably a temporary issue with Wayback.